# How to join a shape key with an armature?

Tags: animation

I'm trying here to join two animations to make it one animation. One of them is shape key and the other one is Armature. Is there any way to join or "marge" them without using code?

Note: I have other shape keys but I just wanna join the blinking animation

[image: As you can see, I wanna join "blinking" shape key with "waiting" Armature!]

Answer (score 2):

One animation acts on an Armature object, while the other acts on a Mesh object, so it's not possible to merge them.

The usual workflow is to add to the armature some control bones and use drivers to make them influence the shape keys, so that a single animation piece will act on bones which directly move vertices and bones which control shape keys.